# SQL query two tables with 2 same value

Tags: sql

I have two tables: `item` table and `detail` table.

In the `item` table I have snum, itemname, description
In the detail I have tnxid, snum, status

What I want to do is output tnxid, snum, itemname, description, status

My problem: how will input all of those that the values along the snum in item table and snum in detail table union together. (both snum must have the same values)

Comment: Sounds like a simple `join` should work.  What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

A simple `JOIN` should suffice

```
Select tnxid
, i.snum
,itemname
,description
,status
from item i
inner join detail d
on i.snum=d.snum
```